# Entering backspace into richtextbox programmatically

Tags: c#

I am attempting to use richtextboxes to display single line mathematical equations. It is essential, therefore, that I can represent exponents.
I have accomplished this by changing the font sizes and offsets as shown here:

```
   {
        if (state) // superscript
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionCharOffset = offSet; 
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Lucinda Console", 10);     

        }
        else  // normal
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionCharOffset = 0;                                     
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Lucinda Console", initialFont);
        }

   richTextBox1.SelectedText = " ";         

    }
```

This body of code is executed with a method, called by a checkbox.
The problem I’m having is that if I don’t append a space, the richtextbox’s char offset and font values default back to nominal the moment I enter it.

I don’t really want a space. I’m only using it to keep the program happy. As a workaround, I am trying to implement a backspace programmatically. Is there a way to do this? I did try using this line of code at the bottom of the block, but it had no effect:

```
richTextBox1.Text.Remove(richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1, 1);

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionCharOffset = offSet;                                    // set the CharOffset to display superscript text. 
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Lucinda Console", 10);                 // set the superscript font;           
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionCharOffset = 0;
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Lucinda Console", initialFont);
        }

        richTextBox1.SelectedText = " ";        
    }
```

Comment: `richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.TrimStart();` or `richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Remove(0,1);`

Comment: @Nofuzy, setting `.Text` on the RichTextBox will **REMOVE** any existing formatting...probably not a desirable side-effect in this scenario!

Answer (score 0):

Just ran a simple test case and all you need to do is give the RichTextBox **FOCUS** to make it update.

Change:

```
richTextBox1.SelectedText = " ";
```

To:

```
richTextBox1.Focus();
```

Comment: I'm afraid that does not work. I just tried it now. The SelectionCharOffset and SelectionFonts do update. They just revert back to their initial values the moment focus is returned to the richtextbox. Unless I append a space.

Comment: Then you've got more going on than you've shown, as it works fine for me.  Edit your original post with more code so we can figure out what's going on.  Show basically anything that modifies/updates your RichTextBox.

Comment: Do note my comment directed at Nofuzy above, if you set `.Text` from anywhere it will reset all of your formatting.  Are you setting `.Text` somewhere in your code?

Comment: I have moved the block of code to the checkBoxChanged event handler. What I should mention is that I am not editing the text programatically. I am entering it directly into the richtextbox - during runtime. Do you think that might be the problem? I'm not modifying the setting .Text anywhere else in my code.

Comment: In my test I was entering text with the keyboard, not programmatically.

Comment: Okay, I solved my problem. I had two additional events - enter and leave. What they did was change the border setting - no border when leaving the richtextbox, and border when editing it. It didn't like that. I followed your advice and looked for every possible modifier. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Glad you found it!